# How to see dependency tree in sbt?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I am trying to inspect the SBT dependency tree as described in the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/inspect.html#taskdependencytree):

```
sbt inspect tree clean
```

But I get this error:

```
[error] inspect usage:
[error]   inspect [uses|tree|definitions] <key>   Prints the value for 'key', the defining scope, delegates, related definitions, and dependencies.
[error]
[error] inspect
[error]        ^
```

What is wrong? Why doesn't SBT build the tree?

Comment: Look at the latest answer from [@TheKojuEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64219001/6658955) for sbt  > 1.4

Answer (score 90, accepted):

*When run from the command line*, each argument sent to sbt is supposed to be a command,  so `sbt inspect tree clean`will:

- run the `inspect` command,
- then run the `tree` command,
- then the `clean` command

This obviously fails, since `inspect` needs an argument. This will do what you want:

```
sbt "inspect tree clean"
```

Comment: What it shows library dependencies?? Dont think so.

Comment: It is working for me, First, I moved to sbt console and run the **inspect tree clean** command. I got big tree of dependencies.

Comment: I tried this, It giving bit tree of things. But I did not fine any external libraries. ie I search for Akka in the output, I did not show any occurrence of Akka in the console. It showing some useless tree. It having all about my local and dependent modules and details only. This command useless. Please help me any command than this nonsense please.

Comment: @Sun: see the second answer for how to get the maven/ivy *library dependencies*, which is what you are looking for. The `inspect tree <foo>` command is about inspecting the dependencies of the task `<foo>` in sbt's task & setting system, which is sometimes useful, but completely different.

Comment: It prints something like a tree. shouldn't be the accepted answer

Comment: No dependencies

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 170):

If you want to actually view the library dependencies (as you would with Maven) rather than the task dependencies (which is what `inspect tree` displays), then you'll want to use the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin.

Add the following to your project/plugins.sbt (or the global plugins.sbt).

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.9.2")
```

Then you have access to the `dependencyTree` command, and others.

Comment: For library dependency info, there are also the detailed dependency reports generated by Ivy. After doing `sbt update`, open the XML reports in `target/resolution-cache/reports/` in a browser like MSIE.

Comment: no way without introducing a library? i start to miss maven :(

Comment: @Jas Even Maven accomplishes this through a plugin, its just that maven grabs the plugin (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin) automatically when you run dependency:tree

Comment: Evicted dependencies and empty lines make it look like a garbage in comparison to maven's clean output.

Comment: + the fact that each dependency repeated each time even if it's already mentioned somewhere before

Comment: Notice the note: "you will more than likely wish to install it as a global plugin so that you can use it in any SBT project without the need to explicitly add it to each one.. ...To do this, add the plugin dependency to ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt for sbt 0.13 or ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt for sbt 1.0"

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz technically it doesn't answer the question, but most people who find this question actually have a different one.

Comment: @Jmes that is no freaking excuse :p Why the h*ll is sbt also not grabbing its own plugin? The UX of sbt sucks big time! :(

Comment: For sbt 1.0 and up, you need this version instead: 
`addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")`
Or have a look at https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph for the latest version and instructions.

Answer (score 99):

With sbt 1.4.0, `dependencyTree` task is available in sbt without using plugins:

```
> sbt dependencyTree
```

sbt-dependency-graph is [included in sbt 1.4.0](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.4-Release-Notes.html#sbt-dependency-graph+is+in-sourced):

> sbt 1.4.0 brings in Johannes Rudolph’s sbt-dependency-graph plugin into the code base. Since it injects many tasks per subprojects, the plugin is split into two parts:
>
> - `MiniDependencyTreePlugin` that is **enabled by default**, bringing in `dependencyTree` task to `Compile` and `Test` configurations
> - Full strength `DependencyTreePlugin` that is enabled by putting the following to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addDependencyTreePlugin
```

See old README for the list of available tasks.

Comment: Thanks! Since sbt 1.4, this is the correct answer. All other answers are more or less outdated. (SO should provide a way to tag answers as outdated or something like that...)

Comment: Based on the output it seems to have a dependency on JDK 11 ```[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.0 (Red Hat, Inc. Java 11.0.9)```. Not bad a thing, but is good to keep in mind.

Comment: It's very annoying that they haven't included all comments in sbt though, I would like to be able to run `dependencyBrowseTree`, but seem to had to add the whole plugin to do that.

Comment: Agree. This should be correct answer for SBT 1.4+

Comment: How to find dependencyTree of a specific jar file?

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 23):

If you want to view **library dependencies**, you can use the `coursier` plugin: https://github.com/coursier/coursier/blob/master/doc/FORMER-README.md#printing-trees

Output example:
[image]
text (without colors): https://gist.github.com/vn971/3086309e5b005576533583915d2fdec4

Note that the plugin has a completely different nature than printing trees. It's designed for fast and concurrent dependency downloads. But it's nice and can be added to almost any project, so I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @mjjaniec thanks! I'll use it for now. By the time it changes, hopefully the web site will have a proper/stabilized entry for this.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using `"net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph"` plugin mentioned above and got 9K lines as the output(there are many empty lines and duplicates) in comparison to ~180 lines(exactly one line for each dependency in my project) as the output in Maven's `mvn dependency:tree` output. So I wrote a sbt wrapper [task](https://gist.github.com/MaxNevermind/e02ed8c185419372874e560c5a489193) for that Maven goal, an ugly hack but it works:

```scala
// You need Maven installed to run it.
lazy val mavenDependencyTree = taskKey[Unit]("Prints a Maven dependency tree")
mavenDependencyTree := {
  val scalaReleaseSuffix = "_" + scalaVersion.value.split('.').take(2).mkString(".")
  val pomXml =
    <project>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <dependencies>
        {
          libraryDependencies.value.map(moduleId => {
            val suffix = moduleId.crossVersion match {
              case binary: sbt.librarymanagement.Binary => scalaReleaseSuffix
              case _ => ""
            }
            <dependency>
              <groupId>{moduleId.organization}</groupId>
              <artifactId>{moduleId.name + suffix}</artifactId>
              <version>{moduleId.revision}</version>
            </dependency>
          })
        }
      </dependencies>
    </project>

  val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(160, 2)
  val pomString = printer.format(pomXml)

  val pomPath = java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile("", ".xml").toString
  val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(new File(pomPath))
  pw.write(pomString)
  pw.close()

  println(s"Formed pom file: $pomPath")

  import sys.process._
  s"mvn -f $pomPath dependency:tree".!
}
```

Comment: your code is really helpful, BTW if anyone trying to run this on windows then please do not forget to write the absolute path of `mvn.cmd` instead of only writing `mvn`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Reference [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph)
For sbt < 1.3 use:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")
```

and then

```
sbt compile:dependencyTree
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [intellij-sbt-dependency-analyzer](https://github.com/bitlap/intellij-sbt-dependency-analyzer) plugin in IDEA now.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `sbt 1.4` add to your `project/plugins.sbt`
the following line as such:

`addDependencyTreePlugin`

then you have those features ready:

```
$ sbt dependencyTree
$ sbt dependencyBrowseTree
$ sbt dependencyBrowseGraph
...
```

the latter two have graphical output in the browser, the `...Tree` one has incremental search capabilities.

( The list of all tasks is still mentioned [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph) even it is yet archived )