# How to debug SBT downloading a package for the wrong scalaVersion

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I tried adding https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv to my project's Build.scala settings. Intellij is set to auto-import, picks up the change and starts downloading packages, after it finishes I can see in the external libraries section that csv-parser_2.10 has been downloaded even though I used %% and our scalaVersion is set to 2.11.4 just like csv-parser is too.

Where and how can I figure out why SBT made the decision to download 2.10 instead of 2.11? When I created a small sample project with only the csv-parser it worked fine.

Comment: show Build.scala, running sbt from command-line works ? how do you know you set the scala version ?

Comment: You can try printing a dependency tree (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414734/1743367 ) and then searching for csv-parser in the tree. You should be able to figure out which other dependencies caused that a different version was installed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the dependency graph sugar plugin from gilt, add

```
addSbtPlugin("com.gilt" % "sbt-dependency-graph-sugar" % "0.7.4")
```

to your global sbt config, for example in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` and you will be able to run `dependencyGraphString` to get a ascii tree of the dependencies where you can figure out where that dependency comes from.

More about the plugin: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: Would it also show not just where the dependency came from, but also what cause the scalaVersion to be set differently?

Comment: It would show which library depends on csv-parser_2.10, which should help you understand what to override/exclude