# Using sbt to find which project included a jar

Tags: sbt

I am trying to figure out which dependency includes the org.json library.  The project clearly contains something that references the org.json library, because I am able to refer to things in that library in the code and it will compile and run.  I tried using sbt "inspect tree clean" but the resulting information did not include "org.json" at all.

Using maven you can do dependency:tree which will show you how every single library that is included got included (by following the dependencies brought in by the dependencies).  In maven I can find a jar (e.g. the org.json one) and move up the dependency tree to figure out which thing I included brought in the library in question.

I would like to do this using sbt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see dependency tree in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519926/how-to-see-dependency-tree-in-sbt)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414734/736957 from the question liked above. Use sbt-dependency-graph plugin.